# Post nuclear underground comic

Tags: story-identification, underground-civilization

There was a comic that told the story of an underground society. A nuclear war was still going on. Radiation was seeping down into their caverns. A scientist was tasked to find a safer location deeper down. However, he found the mutated remnants of an earlier human society that experienced a previous nuclear war. Trying to recall the name of the comic or the story itself.  I am thinking mid 80's when I read this but could be an earlier time when it was written.

Comment: The description matches with *[City of the First Time](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?277046)* by G. J. Barrett, except that it isn't a comic.